# ReactJs - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I did take a research on stackoverflow and received some results which is still not helping me solving this different problem properly. (differences between function and class)

(Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.)
at the line <Product7 key= {products7.id} from that.

I am new to this subject. I really appreciate if anyone could help me ^_^ . Many thanks.

```
function App() {
  var products7 = [
            {
                 name: 'Hollow Knight',
                 id : 1,
                 price: '3$',
                 status : true,
                 image: 'https://yuzu-emu.org/images/game/boxart/hollow-knight.png'
            },

            {
                 name: '60 Second!',
                 id : 2,
                 price: '4$',
                 status : true
                 image: 'https://yuzu-emu.org/images/game/boxart/hollow-knight.png'

            },

            {
                 name: 'Valiant Heart',
                 id : 3,
                 price: '5$',
                 status : true
                 image: 'https://yuzu-emu.org/images/game/boxart/hollow-knight.png'

            },
  ];

  let elements = products7.map((Product7, index) => {
       
       return     

<Product7 key= {products7.id}
          image={products7.image} 
          price={products7.price} > 

          {products7.name}


           </Product7>


  });
```

Comment: JSX you return inside a set of ( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement is not proper. Try this

```
let elements = products7.map((product7, index) => { // variable name updated
       
       return (    
          <Product7 key= {products7.id}
          image={products7.image} 
          price={products7.price} > 
          {products7.name}
          </Product7>
         )

  });
```

Comment: ×I did as follow (try wrapping return) but received this message instead

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 

I also did as the tutorial video I did (the difference is that he used "class" and I used "function"  then I think it may cause somewhere in that). btw thanks for replying my question. Any further help is very appreciated.

Comment: What is your component name? your component name and variable of map is same, i have updated they answer. @ThanhVinh

Comment: the component name is Product7. The variable of map is products7 (added an extra "s"). alright!

Comment: @ThanhVinh `Product7` is also declared in your anonymous function that you passed to your `map`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your return code inside map

```
 let elements = products7.map((Product7, index) => {
       
       return (     

         <Product7 key= {products7.id}
          image={products7.image} 
          price={products7.price} > 

          {products7.name}


           </Product7>)


  });
```

Comment: ×I did as follow (try wrapping return) but received this message instead

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 

I also did as the tutorial video I did (the difference is that he used "class" and I used "function"  then I think it may cause somewhere in that). btw thanks for replying my question. Any further help is very appreciated.